# rails ransack filter by association model field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I want to find records by association model

Example:

```
User.includes(:orders).ransack(orders_id_eq: '1').result.to_sql
```

and result returns

```
SELECT users.* FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN orders ON orders.user_id = users.id WHERE orders.id = NULL;
```

Why id = NULL or id = '1'?

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

Because orders_id_eq is a ransack filter, it will be converted to orders.id = NULL. So, we need to use orders_id_eq_any to filter by association model. Example:

```
User.includes(:orders).ransack(orders_id_eq_any: '1').result.to_sql
```

Comment: It's because id field have type uuid [github.com](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/786)